# Dúvida com procedure, passando nome da tabela como parâmetro no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de criar uma procedure onde vou passar o nome da tabela e Id Tabela como parâmetros, como poderia fazer isso? Tenho o meu exemplo de como gostaria de fazer

```
DECLARE @NomeTabela VARCHAR(50) = 'Region';
DECLARE @IdDaTabela INT = 1;

select  * from Region 
select  @IdDaTabela from @NomeTabela
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução!

```
DECLARE @NomeTabela VARCHAR(50) = 'Region';
DECLARE @NomeIdTabela VARCHAR(50) = 'RegionID';
DECLARE @IdDaTabela INT = 1;

select  * from Region 

execute('SELECT '+ @NomeIdTabela +', * FROM ' + 
                   @NomeTabela + ' where ' +  
                   @NomeIdTabela + ' = ' + 
                   @IdDaTabela )
```